# How can I re-size all display output on a MacBook with letterboxing/mattes, to avoid dead edges of the LCD?

Tags: macos, display, macbook, lcd, resizing

**Context**

My MacBook pro's LCD is damaged. Warranty support and replacement purchase are, at least for several months, impossible for me.

The damage is very specific: only the **left** vertical 1" (around 2.5cm) of the screen are dead, emitting solid grey pixels no matter what (I've tried PRAM reset, re-taping tricks, other operating systems, reseating the LVDS cable . . . trust me, that strip of screen is dead).

Because there are important controls I regularly need to use on the edge of the screen (in the OS and in applications), I need some way to tell OSX to avoid using that edge of the screen for any display content.

**Question**

How can I, using software, tell OSX to resize/reshape the *entire* display so that (at least) the right side of the screen is not used by any display elements?

Put another way: how can I tell OSX to embed padding/black bars *of a configurable width* around its display area on the left and right, and display what it usually would between them.

Any solution must work on a MacBook's internal display; television underscan/overscan is not relevant here.

I'm looking for something like vertical [letterboxing/matting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)).

I am OK with a solution that:

- Letterboxes symmetrically (e.g. loses me an equivalent amount of space on the other, undamaged edge of the screen).
- Distorts the picture displayed on my screen, so long as no content is moved off the screen or rendered invisible. I don't need to see images/videos in perfect, un-skewed fidelity; I just need to see everything (text, diagrams) on the display for my work.
- Requires installation of an older version of OSX (but not a different operating system).
- Requires scary/hacky modification of system internals.

**What I've Tried**

- Compensating manually: dragging windows to the right to avoid the damage. This literally caused me joint damage, and can't address desktop icons that (might?) be in the dead space, or the apple menu/main application menus on the left of the screen.
- I've tried [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/), but have been unable to create a custom resolution for the internal monitor that has sufficient "blanking". Even with SIP disabled, custom resolutions with high blanking won't take.
- [DisplayConfigX](http://www.3dexpress.de/) is incompatible with my version of OSX and, I suspect, my hardware. If others have experiences to the contrary, please speak up.